# How to create a SwiftUI #Preview in Xcode 15 for a view with a @Binding

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode15

If I wanted to create a preview for a SwiftUI view that contains a @Binding I would have previously written something like this:

```
struct SpecialButton_Preview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        @State var value: Bool = true
        SpecialButton(isOn: $value)
    }
}
```

However Xcode 15 now comes with a new syntax (#Preview) but when I try to add my example state property, it does not work:

```
#Preview {  // Error: Ambiguous use of 'Preview(_:traits:body:)'
    @State var value: Bool = true
    SpecialButton(isOn: $value)
}
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to return the View to preview. I'm not exactly sure how this works, it has to do with how Swift macros work.

```swift
#Preview {
    @State var value: Bool = true
    return SpecialButton(isOn: $value)
}
```

From the WWDC Slack:
"The new `#Previews` macro simply takes a closure that returns the thing to be previewed. So you can declare local variables or do other setup necessary in there just like you would in any other closure."

Edit: This only works when you don't want to update the state, otherwise you have to follow the way mentioned by `de.`

Comment: This gives me the following error: `Cannot use explicit 'return' statement in the body of result builder 'ViewBuilder'`

Comment: @Ribena what did your whole code snippet look like? I put this in Xcode 15 beta 1 and it worked (also note this is subject to change because this is a beta Xcode right now)

Comment: Doing this and updating @State variables won't actually trigger a view update. It is needed to wrap it into a wrapper view as suggested by `de.` below.

Answer (score 27):

This is what I ended up doing in order to have a mutable value:

```
#Preview {
    struct PreviewWrapper: View {
        @State var value: Bool = true
        
        var body: some View {
            SpecialButton(isOn: $value)
        }
    }
    return PreviewWrapper()
}
```

Comment: What does doing this accomplish? in this case, you could use what is mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76468419/17309983

Comment: Yep, I am also using preview wrapper to accomplish real stateful previews. Otherwise, state values will not trigger preview updates.

Comment: Correct way!, This was recommended by apple in WWDC 2020 to make sure @state change triggers view change.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I was hoping they would improve this with the new #Preview macro though.

Answer (score 6):

What you could do before and still can do is:

```
SpecialButton(isOn: .constant(true))
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally have a reusable view that I use to allow for the @Binding to be manipulated in the Live Preview. It looks like the following:

```
public struct PreviewBindingWrapper<T, Content: View>: View {
    @State private var wrappedBinding: T
    private let content: (Binding<T>) -> Content

    public init(wrappedBinding: T, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping (Binding<T>) -> Content) {
        self._wrappedBinding = State(wrappedValue: wrappedBinding)
        self.content = content
    }

    public var body: some View {
        content($wrappedBinding)
    }
}
```

This can then be used in your preview like:

```
#Preview {
    PreviewBindingWrapper(true) { booleanBinding in
        SpecialButton(isOn: booleanBinding)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks - I have a similar error: Ambiguous use of 'init(_:traits:body:)'

```
#Preview {
    NewPositionView(symbol: .constant("AAPL") )
}
```

& with a @State var without the return inside of Preview
Error:  Result of 'NewPositionView' initializer is unused

This fixed it... adding the return inside #Preview

```
#Preview {
    @State var sym: String = "AAPL"
    return NewPositionView(symbol: $sym )
}
```

Comment: But can you mutate the state interactively like in the version with the WrapperView?

Answer (score -3):

Do you need to keep it as a binding var in your preview? Otherwise try this, as it seems to work for me:

```
#Preview {
    SpecialButton(isOn: true)
}
```

I'd elaborate on the 'why' but that's still unclear!

Comment: Yes, the whole point is to preview "a SwiftUI view that contains a @Binding".

Comment: @de. ...which my solution does, in a way? In my seemingly identical case, it allows my View containing a @Binding to be previewed whereas none of the other currently stated solutions work for me. Are you not getting `Cannot use explicit 'return' statement in the body of result builder 'ViewBuilder'` when you try the accepted solution, as I did when I tried it with the code you've provided?